# How to clean tv plasma screen

Tags: screens

What should I use for cleaning a TV plasma screen? My three-year-old daughter has put her hands many times on the screen and there is a big spot on it.
I don't live in America, so maybe I'm not able to buy a known American brand, but I'll appreciate any kind of guide.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because cleaning a TV screen is outside the site scope per the Help Center.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is water (distilled) and microfiber cloth.  There are tons of screen cleaners on the market that you can order though that are a little easiest to work with than water.

Comment: I actually use a dry microfiber or with some windex -- water won't cut through the oil deposits and using it just seems to make it harder to clean.

Comment: @Ethereal - I wouldn't use anything with alcohol or ammonia.  Both of these can eat away at the coatings they put on the newer TVs.  If you have an oil issue I would just dip part of microfiber cloth in kitchen sink that has a little water and Dawn.  You are going to ruin your TV with the Windex after one time but if you keep doing it, you will have issues if you have an anti-glare film.

Comment: I also use microfiber and very dilute dish soap. I would use caution with a chemical as my wife tried to clean a large rear projection TV that a grand son touched with peanut butter and jelly fingers, it did damage the screen and that was when a 65" cost over 3k. +

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you want a non-scratching cloth or towel -- if you're aiming for near-perfection, the "lens wipes" sold for cleaning microscope lenses are a good way to go. With respect to the fingerprints, you'll be able to remove fingerprints if you use something in which the oils are at least a bit soluble. The key is to avoid an aggressive solvent (as DMoore notes...) which may also eat away at the screen coating(s). I generally use 35% isopropanol -- this concentration is low enough that it's unlikely to have much of an effect on a screen coating.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. I'd be concerned about using anything with alcohol in it... the OP should try it in a small corner before wiping a big streak across the middle.